# What was the relationship between Whitebeard and Roger?

Tags: one-piece

Indeed, they have a peculiar relationship. Towards the end of the battle at Marineford, he had a fashback to some time he spent with Roger, and how he was not interested in Raftel at all even if Roger told him where it was. How come then, that earlier than that, when Shanks confronted him about stopping Ace from the pursuit of Blackbeard, he admitted that they used to fight a lot with Roger's ship.

Yes we know no pirates have any proper relation, but would someone like Doffy have a cup of tea with Crocodile at all? Not to mention the enormous secret Roger was just about to reveal so casually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just ***friendly rivals***. Similar in vein to Shanks and Mihawk.
Knowing Roger (he had a similar personality as Luffy, noted by Rayleigh and Shanks himself) he was free spirited. If there was a Yonko at that time that would be Roger, Whitebeard, and Shiki. The only difference was Roger rose to the top and became Pirate King before his execution.

Being the top dogs during their era, it's without question that they would engage each other in fights against each other but end up settling it with a laugh after the fight. Roger trusts WB and likewise, WB trusts Roger hence the drinking scene.

Comment: I agree with that, but shanks and miwhawk are rivals who wished to surpass eachother but they didn't "fight" for real.

Comment: @TGamer They did, until Shanks lost an arm

Comment: They did fight for real until Shanks lost his arm. Mihawk stopped challenging him because of his "_handicap_".

That's the predicament of Mihawk. Fight a guy who lost an "arm" and win or fight a guy who lost an arm and lose? Either way his pride as a swordsman is at stake.

Comment: I do believe Shanks didn't get weak because of his arm. In fact, I can argue he's stronger than he has ever been now. His haki clash with WB in WB's ship and his presence alone in the Battle of Marineford was enough to prove it. I think its just Mihawk's pride as a swordsman that he sees a man losing an arm is a handicap that's why he wagered raising his own rival, Zoro.

Edit: One can be a better swordsman but one should also consider the other part, fighting prowess. In the world of One Piece, technique alone can't save you. This is why Haki is so great.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 That is not what I mean

Comment: @ShanCoralde I mean that fighting for rivalry is different that legit fighting to death or something. I mean like Garp fought against Don Chinjao, it wasn't a friendly fight as was the case between miwhaek and shanks; they didn't fight to destroy each other for another cause as the marines would do the pirates.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that Whitebeard and Roger had a rivalry akin to Garp and Chinjao. Let me clear things up, Whitebeard and Roger never fought to the death as the manga had shown. WB and Roger are _similar_ to _Shanks and Mihawk_. They trust each other even if they are rivals. This is why Roger was even willing to tell the location of the One Piece to WB. Just like the way Mihawk informed Shanks about Luffy's bounty. They just had a casual drink. Chinjao and Garp had a one-sided rivalry. Garp views CJ as nothing but a pirate that needs to be stop, no lingering feelings like Roger's.